# How to serve my directory over internet

Tags: server, tunnel, connection-sharing

I use `python -m http.server 8080` to serve my directory over LAN.
But how will I serve my directory over Internet.

I use pageKite and ngrok to access my machine from Internet.

Thanking you for correcting and guiding me.

Comment: If I understand correctly, both pagekite and ngrok websites have guides and tutorials how to do it. Basically, you run their client software on your machine, configure everything in their web panel and you get an URL under which you can access your site. Use these guides!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python http.server is more of a "makeshift" web server compared to something like Nginx or Apache. But if this is what you're looking for you should be able to run the command below, replacing the URL with yours, and the URL should point towards your Python http.server.

Note that your Python http.server must still be running for it to be accessable. So either run it in another terminal tab/window or background it by putting the `&` at the end of the command before running pagekite.

```
python2 pagekite.py 8080 <replaceME>.pagekite.me
```